Indexing dataframe with pandas
I have a dataframe which is made with 4 columns like this

As you can see the "indexing" (row number) is not correct.
Is there a way start it from 0 and increase it?

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) 

should work fine
